# Using "Style" in a variable

Tags: html, css, vbscript, wsh

At the moment, all I'm trying to do is get the style in this piece of HTML to display in a `WScript.Echo` popup.  I cannot find the correct syntax to do this.  The value I want is: `"width: 0%;"` (or whatever the value happens to be).

HTML:

```html
<div class="progress" id="progress-bar-current-progress" style="width: 0%;">
```

Here are some things I've tried (on some of these I'm just stabbing in the dark):

```vb
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").getAttribute("style").innertext
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").getAttribute    ("style").innerhtml
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.width
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.innertext
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.innerhtml
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementById("progress-bar-current-progress")(1)
wscript.echo ie.document.all.item("progress-bar-current-progress").innerText
wscript.echo ie.document.all.item("progress-bar-current-progress").innerHtml
wscript.echo ie.document.all.item("progress-bar-current-progress").cssText
wscript.echo ie.document.all.item("progress-bar-current-progress").getAttribute("style")
wscript.echo ie.document.all.item("progress-bar-current-progress")(1)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(2)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(3)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(4)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(5)
wscript.echo ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```vb
style = ie.document.getElementById("progress-bar-current-progress").getAttribute("style")
WScript.Echo style
```

If it doesn't you need to show your code as well as any error you're getting.

Comment: The echo box pops up, but it's blank.

Comment: Well, I already did suggest a course of action for this scenario, didn't I?

Comment: If you are referring to posting my code, I did that after your first response.  It's not showing up - says it has to be peer reviewed.  Out of my control.  It's just basic vbscript navigating to URLs from a text file.  In the meantime: http://pastebin.com/43sphQQ7

Comment: Any ideas on things I could try?

Comment: Do not post links to pastebins. The code belongs in your question. Also, what does the rest of the HTML look like? Does it contain frames or iframes? What happens if you remove the `On Error Resume Next` from your VBScript?

Comment: *If you are referring to posting my code, I did that after your first response.* [No, you didn't](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32709416/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

You can just get style property value from jQuery like this,

```
var style = $("#progress-bar-current-progress").attr('style');
```

Comment: How do use this with vbscript?